# ¿Como puedo mandar un archivo PDF a una impresora por "LPR" desde vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Me gustaría saber como mandar un archivo PDF a una impresora por "LPR" desde vb.net

Se que el comando que debo ejecutar es "lpr -S 192.168.70.15 -P red " + filename" pero lo intento desde Process en Windows10 y no le llega nada. Este es mi codigo:

```
Dim lprProcess As New Process()
With lprProcess.StartInfo
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .FileName = "cmd.exe"
    .Arguments = "/c LPR -S " & serverLpr & " -P red -o l" & file
End With
lprProcess.Start()
```

Comment: Si lo ejecutas directamente desde una linea de comandos te funciona? Por que si no me equivoco, lpr no está disponible en windows 10 por ejemplo. Que sistema operativo tienes?

Comment: Desde la linea de comandos si me funciona, lpr ya lo habilité desde agregar herramientas de windows.

Comment: Intenta entonces añadir despues de `lprProcess.Start()` `lprProcess.WaitForExit()`, a ver si se queda la ventana de comandos abierta y puedes ver que error te está dando

Comment: De todas maneras, creo que te falta un espacio en blanco despues de `..red -ol `, se te está juntando la `l `con el nombre del archivo

Comment: Me cierra la consola, no consigo ver el error.

Comment: probaste a añadir un espacio en blanco despues de  `-o l `?

Comment: Muchas gracías, al final he sacado el comando con un Debug.Print() para ver si estaba pasando algo mal, le he quitado el "-o l" y he dejado los espacios pertinentes y ya lo he conseguido.

Comment: ¿Por cierto, como puedo hacer para puntuarte positivamente, que soy nuevo en stackoverflow?

Comment: No puedes ya que los comentarios no se puntúan. Pero no te preocupes, en realidad esta pregunta se puede considerar _problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos._. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto :)

Comment: Entonces debería cerrarse

Comment: Como se cierra un hilo?

Comment: En breve será cerrado. Aqui no hay "hilos" (no es un foro), son publicaciones, que constan de una pregunta y una o varias respuestas. El cierre lo puede hacer la comunidad mediante votación (5 votos de usuarios con la suficiente reputación son necesarios). Si tienes cualquier duda mas, revisa el [tour] y tambien [meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Por cierto, bienvenido a la comunidad! :)